# how to remove whitespace between two words in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a record like `Z Ion Fort`. Now I want to combine the word like as follows `ZIon Fort`,for that I had written a update query like

```
 update sample1 set sname=replace(sname,' Ion ','Ion ');
```

But it is not working.

Comment: You have to use a sub select for this. See the manuals for sub queries.

Comment: please give sample example for that,because i,m new for mysql.i dont know how to use sub select for removing for spaces between words.

Comment: It worked on mine as is. You might have to do a manual COMMIT and refresh the table views, but your example was fine with no changes.

Comment: Are you sure ` Ion` starts with the capital `I` in your real data? `REPLACE()` is a case sensitive function...

Comment: yes in 'Ion', 'I' is the capital letter in my real data

Comment: Then your whitespace is not a single space it's rather several spaces or tab `\t`. We can't keep guessing. If you want to be helped post sample of your real (or fake) data on which your update statement is not working

Comment: my original data is                                            tradename
                                                                    -------------------
                                                                    Z Ion Fort
                                                                    Z Butol (800 mg) i want to remove space between Z and Ion,Z and Butol.

Comment: Why isn't it working? I suggest you use PHP to fix the string, then write it back to MySQL.

Comment: @StephenO'Flynn is right. See [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c55ea/2/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47374/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE sample1
    (`sname` varchar(36))
;

INSERT INTO sample1
    (`sname`)
VALUES
    ('Z Ion Fort Z Butol (800 mg)')
;



update sample1 set sname=replace(sname,'Z ','Z');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from sample1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47374/1/0)**:

```
|                     SNAME |
|---------------------------|
| ZIon Fort ZButol (800 mg) |
```